# How do I do an Integration of the real part of a complex function from zero to infinity?

Tags: python, scipy, complex-numbers, numerical-integration

This is a equation I want to implement as a function in Python.
[image: This is a equation I want to implement as a function in Python.]
`r`, `t`, `T`, `a`, and `b` are all specific figures. `φ` is defined as `φR +φi*i` where `φR` is set to 0.5 and `φi` is used for the integration. `erf()` is the standard complex error function.

First I defined:

```
def A(phii, tau):
    A = (2*mu*lam)/(2*mu*kk-sigv**2)*np.log(1+((sigv**2-2*mu*kk)*(phir+phii*i))/(2*kk*(1-mu*    (phir+phii*i)))*(np.exp(-kk*tau)-1))
    return A

def B(phii, tau):
    B = (-2*kk*theta)/(sigv**2)*np.log(1+(sigv**2*(phir+phii*i))/(2*kk)*(np.exp(-kk*tau)-1))
    return B

def D(phii, tau):
    D = (2*kk*(phir+phii*i))/(sigv**2*(phir+phii*i)+(2*kk-sigv**2*(phir+phii*i))*np.exp(kk*tau))
    return D

def funct(phii, tau, V):
    funct = np.exp(B(phii,tau)+D(phii,tau)*V+A(phii,tau))
    return funct
```

Where `funct()` is `f()` in the picture above.
All the variables besides `φi` are set to a specific figure.

```
def RE(phii, tau, X, K):
    feh = erf(K*np.sqrt((phir+phii*1j)/a)) # error function 
    feh = feh.real

    RE = np.exp(((phir+phii*1j)*b)/a)*funct(phii, tau, ((X**2)-b)/a)*(1-feh)/((np.sqrt((phir+phii*1j)/a))**3)
    REreal = RE.real
    return REreal

phii_val = np.linspace(0,2000)
tau = 1
X = 0.13
K = 0.13
trap = integrate.trapezoid(RE(phii_val,tau,X,K),phii_val)
tratqu = scipy.integrate.quad(lambda phii: RE(phii,tau,X,K),0,np.inf)[0]
tratres = (np.exp(-r*tau))/(2*a*np.sqrt(np.pi))*trap
tratresu = (np.exp(-r*tau))/(2*a*np.sqrt(np.pi))*tratqu
```

I tried to use quad and trapezoid for my integration but not only do they differ a lot in results (which I guess is not that uncommon) but also both do not give me the right result. Now I was wondering if I have any mistakes in my integration or if I have done other mistakes?

Comment: Aren't you getting the real part of ERF too soon? you compute feh, then take its real part and sue only that for the RE computation, but I would assume you have to use the full complex value, and only extract the real part of the final result, as you do for REreal

Comment: ah yes, I just played around with that. you are correct but unfortunately changing that does not help my results. They are still wrong.

Comment: Yeah, then my other point of concern is that your integration bins have width 1, which could be too large and introduce there a lot of integration error.  In general the rest of the definitions seem ok to me

Comment: If my integration is alright since I checked for integration bins, I suspect my error term to be the problem. The term with the error function in it, is very small (close to zero) which leads to the integration being close to zero. Do you have any idea what could be the problem here?

Comment: there are a lot of things in your code that come from somewhere else, so I am not able to check any specific results. If you are not sure about the implementation, check if each term produces the correct values for a given phi_i.  Terms goin go to zero is not necessarily bad, if it didn't, the integral would never converge. The problem would only appear if they go to zero when they are not supposed to (because of some wrong implementation)

Comment: I´ve gone trough everything and I dont think its a problem of implementation anymore. K is set to ten (not my decision since its a paper replication). The error term is automatically rather close to one which leads the term with the error function to be close to 0. This leads the endresult to be close to 0, which is not the result in the paper. I am not sure if you could help me here but do you see where I am mistaken here?

Comment: Add the link to that paper on the question

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10203-011-0124-0

Comment: Given the form of that error term, I would look again at the integration bins. Depending on `a`, the argument for that error function would be small only for sqrt(phi/a) << K, if a is close to one (is it?), then the error function is close to zero only for very small values of  phi. If you only integrate with bin size 1, you loose the granularity that you would need for that region

Comment: That might also explain why the two methods differ so much, if only the first bin contributes to the integral (as any phi larger than one leads to the function being zero), and the integration bin as a large amount of error, you basically just see their respective errors

Comment: I would like to help here, but can you give representative values of r, t, T, a, and b? It looks like you're using tau = 1, K=0.13, and X = 0.13 - and you're using capital X to represent the lower case x seen in thr equations? Can you show the function `f` mathematically? It sounds like you have a reference value for the result - care to share it?

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZWdd.png
 [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3Obi.png
r = 0.0319
kk = 3.46 
mu = 0.05
sigv = 0.14
theta = 0.008
mubar = -0.1
lam = 0.47
pj = -0.38
phir = 0.2
mus = -0.086
a = 0.8703809422332588
b = 0.007123753546800098
tau = 1 but here you could more or less choose freely between like 0.1 
and 1
X and K = 13. Here I am not completely sure. X and K are normally given 
in percent so 0.13 but in the paper they always say 13 so I would assume 
13 is here correct. 
(t - T) = tau
V = (X**2-b)/a